# CMS database schema

Tags: php, mysql, database, content-management-system, structure

I'm building a custom CMS system usign PHP and MySQL. My CMS will have pages. Each page is of a type. Each page type has assigned some properties of different types (number, text, etc.). I'm currently creating the database for storing these things - page types, properties, pages and property values. The first solution is to have 4 different tables:

```
=pages=
page_id
page_type_id
page_name

=page_types=
page_type_id
page_type_name

=page_properties=
property_id
property_name

=page_property_values=
page_id
property_id
property_value
```

The only problem is, that I would have to save all kind of properties to the same data type filed (for example varchar). What I really want is to save boolean data to boolean field.

My second solution is to create a separate table for each page type. For example:

```
=page_type_text_page=
page_id
title [varchar]
content [text]
active [boolean]
```

Could somebody help me, how to modify this structure in order to get the right solution?

Answer (score 0):

I would like to help you with some of my experiences:

1. Do not build your own CMS - it may not be a good idea. It is very complicated to do it right. Use/modify some open-source CMS (Wordpress, Joomla, etc) to get what you want.
2. If I would be creating a new CMS do not use PHP and MySQL combination, because it's already done, and it's done pretty good with great community. Maybe you can try something thats not done yet - Node.js CMS, Single page application CMS and use some mongoDB etc.
3. If you really want build your own CMS based on PHP MySQL and don't know right database structure, inspire yourself with open-source CMS, like I said Wordpress, Joomla, Drupal etc. Its more complicated than what you describe, but you can use only what you want.

Answer (score 0):

A third option might be something in the lines of

**property_types**

- property_type_id
- property_name
- property_datatype

**page_property_values**

- page_id
- property_id
- property_stringvalue
- property_boolvalue
- property_intvalue
- property_datetimevalue
- ...

..where you'd use just one of the value columns for a certain page property and leave the rest empty. This way you would be able to get all the properties for a page in a single call with a couple of joins and then programatically fetch the value from the apropriate column by looking at the property data type.